# Gnome extension 'Alt Tab: Raise First Window' cannot be disabled

Tags: gnome, alt-tab

I'm new to Linux and I'm using Pop!_OS 20.10 x86_64. The system by default enables an extension **Alt Tab: Raise First Window** and I cannot *disable* it: I disable the extension from **Gnome Tweaks** and also disable it from **Extension** app (green icon). But `Alt` + `Tab` still just raise one window.

Example: I opened two folders in two windows. Press `Alt`+`Tab`, just one folder shows (the last used one). It should show two options to raise one of the opened folders (like most Alt+Tab does). But with I only get one choice so I cannot switch folders.

[image: Example taken from another machine] This image is what I expect (not what I get).

Could anybody help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? And I can't workout what **is** happening.

Comment: For example, I open two folders, then press `Alt`+`Tab`. It should show two options to raise one of the opened folders (like most `Alt`+`Tab` does). But with I only get one choice so I cannot switch folders.

Sorry for my poor English. I hope I made myself clear. @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: Are not your two arrows pointing at two choices? What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, there are two choices in the picture, and that's what I want it to be. The picture is captured from another machine. On my Pop!_OS, I only get one choice. @ctrl-alt-delor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between applications, not windows, in GNOME 3. The companion shortcut, which allows to switch brtween multiple windows of that application, depends on the keyboard layout and is usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. Of course, you could also navigate to a window graphically with arrow keys while the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed.

The extension "Alt Tab: Raise First Window" is not supposed to replace switching between applications with switching between windows. It only defines whether all windows of the application are brought to you on top of other open windows when you switch to that application, but it does not add a way to select a window of that application.

You can switch between windows of all applications with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. This switches between the windows immidiately without showing options visually. The shortcut is named "Switch windows directly".

You can also switch between windows the same way as between applications with a visual summary of all open windows, like on your screenshot. By default, this shortcut is not set. It is named "Switch windows". You can set it in Settings under Keyboard.

You can even assign it  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to make it switch windows instead of applications. If you change your mind, you will need to restore "Switch applications" shortcut.